# Reading bytes from a binary file

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, binaryfiles, bitwise-operators

I have got a binary file and i need to store from `( x, y )` position `z` amount of bytes. For example I have got this sequence of bytes :

```
00000000  49  49  49  49  05  00  00  00   08  00  00  00  1a  00  00  00 | y0 
00000010  39  a6  82  f8  47  8b  b8  10   78  97  f1  73  56  d9  6f  00 | y1
00000020  58  99  d5  3b  ac  7b  7b  40   b6  2e  9f  0a  69  b2  ac  a0 | y2
          ________________________________________________________________
          x0  x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6  x7   x8  x9  x10 x11 x12 x13 x14 x15
```

Every 2 merged numbers represents 1 byte ( it's taken from hexdump -C - coding is a little endian ). `49` = 1 byte, `f8` is 1 byte etc ...

`( x , y )` means position. For example if i put for x = 2,y = 2 i get position `( 2, 2 )` that means i start reading bytes from position y2, x2. In this case i start at byte `d5` If i put `z = 3` that means i want to store 3 bytes in this case those bytes are `d5, 3b, ac`.

I can calculate the position by a simple formula :

```
position = 16 * y + x  
position = 16 * 2 + 2    // i put x = 2, y = 2 to formula
position = 34    // get number 34, that means i will start storing at 35th byte in this case it's d5
binaryFile . seekg ( position )  // jump to position in a file ( itc it's 99 )
binaryFile . read ( ( char * )&dest, z )) // save z bytes
```

If i put `z = 3` i will store 3 bytes : `d5, 3b, ac`.

But somtimes coefficient `z , x , y` are not integers:

If i put `y = 2, x = 1,5 and z = 3 // ( 1,5, 2 )` That means i have to jump at byte not `99` but `d5` then store 2 bytes in this case `d5 , 3b` and add to them half byte from byte `99` and half byte from byte `ac` because the starting position was `x = 1,5`. How could I do that ??

Comment: There's something just plain *wrong* with using a function named `read` to store bytes.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Could you give a bit of background info about why you're trying to achieve this ? And then we might be able to come up with a better approach.

Comment: @Sander De Dycker i'm trying to cut part of screen from screen. In my example 1 pixel represents 1 byte so it's easy and everything is fine but there are screens where 1 pixel is not 1 byte but for example 12 bits. The position ( x , y ) actually tells at which pixel i start reading not byte. I choosed the simplest example 1 pixel = 1 byte. In the example x = 1,5 may occur when 1 pixel is not 1 byte but for example 4 bits or 12 bits

Comment: In that case, I'd propose introducing an extra variable for the pixel size. You probably also want to change the meaning of `x` and `y` to be pixel coordinates, rather than coordinates in a hex dump. And then, with the aid of these variables, treat the input data as a stream of pixels of the given pixel size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to extend to byte boundaries on both ends, and first read the area that you want to write. So, if you want to write two bytes, you will have to read three bytes.

Then you will have to do appropriate bit shifting and masking to get your bits in the right places.

For example, if you are going to write two bytes shifted ½ byte, you would start with something like this:

```
unsigned char *mydata = MyDataToWrite();
unsigned char temp[bigEnough];
binaryFile.input(temp, 3);
temp[0] = (temp[0] & 0xf0) | (mydata[0] >> 4);
// more code here to put bits in temp
binaryFile.output(temp, 3);
```

Once you have your data in `temp`, write the 3 bytes back to the same location from which the were read.

I'm not going to write the whole thing here, but I hope this gives you an idea you can work from